# How should I recode my Phalcon v2 PhalconCrypt php to work with v3?

Tags: php, encryption, phalcon

I currently have this in my Phalcon v2 code:

```
$di->setShared('crypt', function () {
    $crypt = new PhalconCrypt();
    $crypt->setMode(MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
    $crypt->setKey('mysecretkey');
    return $crypt;
});
```

I am getting this error when running it under Phalcon 3.4.5

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Phalcon\Crypt::setMode()
```

How would I recode it for Phalcon 3.4.5? It isn't clear to me from the documentation how I set the encryption mode in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this line in the sourcecode: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/65183349743e899977adc643f103b887612ffe98/phalcon/crypt.zep#L391, it looks like you add it when you set the encryption cipher.

`->setCipher('aes-256-cfb')`

The documentation says the default cipher is `aes-256-cfb`, so it looks like you don't need to set the mode manually anymore.

https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/crypt